# How to include external jar dependency to maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

While running my app as a Java Application, the included jar in projects Build Path is found and runs without any error. When I try to run the application by executing `java -jar myApp.jar` the used class from the external jar isn't found.

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.escomled.blackboard.impl.BlackboardImpl] for bean with name 'blackboard' defined in class path resource [appContext.xml];

Comment: Use the Maven Shade plugin.

Comment: Something like this?
`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <artifactSet>
        <includes>
         <include>escomled:escomled-common:jar:0.0.1</include>
        </includes>
       </artifactSet>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
`

Comment: Please use an more recent version of the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the external jar to your classpath, if it hasn't been combined by any maven plugin.

```
java -cp <path to external jar> -jar myApp.jar
```

Comment: `java -cp C:\Users\venci.mihalov\Desktop\Escomled Projects\escomled_
common\target\escomled-common-0.0.1.jar -jar escomled-machine-learning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`
**Error: Could not find or load main class Projects\escomled_common\target\escomled-common-0.0.1.jar**

Comment: If you have spaces inside your path, you need to wrap it inside double quotes or escape the space.

Comment: Still the same error
**Cannot find class [com.escomled.blackboard.impl.BlackboardImpl] for bean with name 'blackboard' defined in class path resource [config/appContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.escomled.blackboard.impl.BlackboardImpl**

Comment: Are you sure that jar contains that class?

Comment: Yes, when I open the jar, the class file is in directory _com/escomled/blackboard/impl_